# Need to transfer xsd (xml schema) + xsl into html code

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt, xsd

I am trying the second day, but I didn't find anything as helpful as I need.
I have a code, which transfers xml + xsl into html, but I have to use xml schemas (.xsd) instead of xmls to render html forms based on .xsd and .xsl (styles).

My transfer function (xml + xsl into html):

```
public static HtmlString RenderXml(this HtmlHelper helper, string xml, string xsltPath)
    {
        xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(("C:/Users/Student/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/MvcApplication2/MvcApplication2/complex-sample.xsd"));

        XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
        XslCompiledTransform t = new XslCompiledTransform();
        t.Load(xsltPath);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings))
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            t.Transform(reader, args, writer);
            HtmlString htmlString = new HtmlString(writer.ToString());
            return htmlString;
        }
    }
```

Anyone could help with it?

Comment: When generating an xml using a schema in my opinion once you validated your code you do not need to validate every message sent to a schema.   The code already has been validated.

Comment: If processing the XSD as the XML it is does not produce the desired result, then it is entirely unclear to me what the desired result would be.  We are unlikely to be able to help you without a better characterization of the problem including, at least, short example input, the corresponding desired output, and the stylesheet you're working on.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're trying to solve the right problem?  Is it possible that you're meant to write a transform for XML files that validate against the schemas, as opposed to a transform for the schema documents themselves?

Comment: I just want to transfer .xsd file to generate a html form schema using .xsl file to add styles to them.
I added my .xsd file in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Any XSD is an XML so you can process it you like any other XML.

I do not have any example ready that generates a form but this might be helpful http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200012/msg00083.html.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Tried with few files. When I am using xml + xslt, then it creates nice form with various styles, but when i am trying to upload xsd + xslt, it shows some raw text, which is not even whole text from this .xsd file :(

Comment: You have to add the processing instruction at the top of the XSD.

Comment: Do I have to copy this code from your link at the top of my XSD file, just in front of .xsd content? It does not work that way.

Comment: What XSLT are you using? You have to customize the XSLT so it processes it XSDs.

You can test this by adding <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your_stylesheet_here.xsl" ?> to the top of the XSD and opening it in a browser.

Comment: I just got XSLT and XSD files from client, so I have to assume that both arre correct, I tried to test this in a browser, just the same way as you wrote, but it displays the same, exactly as my application. Can it be an error due to bad input files?

Comment: It seems that files are rather correct, because I tried with 3 various forms.
There is a link to one of these forms:
http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2014/07/28/1724/

I am trying really hard, but there no implementations for XSD files in C# and that for XML does not work for me. I am not even sure if that is program's fault or maybe I am using wrong files to create a view.

Answer (score 0):

my .XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:adr="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/adres/2009/11/09/" xmlns:typ="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/typy/2009/11/16/" xmlns:meta="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/meta/2009/11/16/" xmlns:str="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/struktura/2009/11/16/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ins="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/instytucja/2009/11/16/" xmlns:os="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/osoba/2009/11/16/" xmlns="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2016/12/22/3790/" targetNamespace="http://crd.gov.pl/wzor/2016/12/22/3790/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/struktura/2009/11/16/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/struktura/2009/11/16/struktura.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/adres/2009/11/09/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/adres/2009/11/09/adres.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/osoba/2009/11/16/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/osoba/2009/11/16/osoba.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/typy/2009/11/16/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/typy/2009/11/16/typy.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/instytucja/2009/11/16/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/instytucja/2009/11/16/instytucja.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/meta/2009/11/16/" schemaLocation="http://crd.gov.pl/xml/schematy/meta/2009/11/16/meta.xsd"/>
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Wniosek o wydanie wypisów i wyrysów z miejscowego
        planu zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="Dokument" type="DokumentTyp"/>
<xsd:complexType name="DokumentTyp">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="OpisDokumentu" type="str:OpisDokumentuTyp"/>
        <xsd:element name="DaneDokumentu" type="str:DaneDokumentuTyp"/>
        <xsd:element name="TrescDokumentu" type="TrescDokumentuTyp"/>
        <xsd:element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="TrescDokumentuTyp" mixed="false">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xsd:extension base="str:TrescDokumentuTyp">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="adr:Miejscowosc"/>
                <xsd:element name="Data" type="xsd:date">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>Data</xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Urzad" type="str:Tekst200Typ">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>Do</xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>

                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element name="Wnioskodawca">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                Wnioskodawca - osoba fizyczna
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element ref="os:Nazwisko" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="1">
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element ref="os:Imie"/>
                                <xsd:element ref="os:PESEL" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>

                                <xsd:element ref="adr:Adres"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="WnioskodawcaOsobaPrawna">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>
                                Wnioskodawca - osoba prawna
                            </xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="Nazwa" type="ins:NazwaInstytucjiTyp">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:documentation>
                                            Nazwa
                                        </xsd:documentation>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element ref="ins:NIP" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element ref="ins:REGON" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="Adres" type="adr:AdresTyp">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:documentation>
                                            Adres siedziby
                                        </xsd:documentation>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="Wniosek">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Zwracam się z prośbą o
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:choice>
                                <xsd:element name="WydaniaWypisu">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:documentation>
                                            wydanie wypisu
                                        </xsd:documentation>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="z miejscowego planu zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="ze studium uwarunkowań i kierunków zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="WydaniaWyrysu">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:documentation>
                                            wydanie wyrysu
                                        </xsd:documentation>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="z miejscowego planu zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="ze studium uwarunkowań i kierunków zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="WydanieWypisuWyrysu">
                                    <xsd:annotation>
                                        <xsd:documentation>
                                            wydanie wypisu i wyrysu
                                        </xsd:documentation>
                                    </xsd:annotation>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="z miejscowego planu zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="ze studium uwarunkowań i kierunków zagospodarowania przestrzennego gminy (miasta)">
                                            </xsd:enumeration>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:choice>
                            <xsd:element name="DaneNieruchomosci">
                                <xsd:annotation>
                                    <xsd:documentation>
                                        Dane nieruchomości
                                    </xsd:documentation>
                                </xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="Dzialka" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                                            <xsd:annotation>
                                                <xsd:documentation>
                                                    Działka
                                                </xsd:documentation>
                                            </xsd:annotation>
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element ref="meta:Identyfikator">
                                                        <xsd:annotation>
                                                            <xsd:documentation>
                                                                Identyfikator działki
                                                            </xsd:documentation>
                                                        </xsd:annotation>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="NumerDzialki" type="str:Tekst65Typ">
                                                        <xsd:annotation>
                                                            <xsd:documentation>
                                                                Numer
                                                                działki
                                                            </xsd:documentation>
                                                        </xsd:annotation>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="KartaMapy" type="str:Tekst65Typ" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                                                        <xsd:annotation>
                                                            <xsd:documentation>
                                                                Karta
                                                                mapy
                                                            </xsd:documentation>
                                                        </xsd:annotation>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="Obreb" type="str:Tekst65Typ">
                                                        <xsd:annotation>
                                                            <xsd:documentation>
                                                                Obręb
                                                                (w
                                                                przypadku
                                                                braku
                                                                obrębu
                                                                karta
                                                                mapy)
                                                            </xsd:documentation>
                                                        </xsd:annotation>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:choice>
                                                        <xsd:element ref="adr:Ulica" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                                                        </xsd:element>
                                                        <xsd:element ref="adr:Adres" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                                                        </xsd:element>
                                                    </xsd:choice>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element ref="str:Zalaczniki"/>
                <xsd:element name="InformacjeDodatkowe" type="str:Tekst2000Typ" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Informacje dodatkowe
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="FormaOdbioru">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Forma odbioru dokumentów
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Drogą elektroniczną poprzez skrzynkę kontaktową">
                            </xsd:enumeration>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Poprzez pocztę tradycyjną">
                            </xsd:enumeration>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Osobiście w siedzibie urzędu">
                            </xsd:enumeration>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

my .XSLT file is at link (too long to attach here)

http://wklej.org/id/3210253/

Comment: added link to this post